# Django take value from url

Tags: python, django, ajax, methods, get

I have problem with take value from url (`?site=value`). When I had function in views.py it was work, but now I moved this to another file. Can someone solve this problem?

functionAjax.py:

```
def htmlMain(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        UrlCut = request.GET.get('site','Main')
        Messages = NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data').values()
        context = {
            "Messags" : Messages
        }
        return render(request, 'ajax'+UrlCut+'.html', context)
```

AjaxFunction.js:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
        return null;
     }
     else{
        return results[1] || 0;
     }
}

let tech = ""
if($.urlParam('site') != null)
{
    tech = "?site=" + $.urlParam('site');
}

UrlSet = "/get/ajax/validate/MainSite"+tech;
$.ajax({                                                                                                                           
    url: UrlSet,
    data: $('#FormSite').serialize(), 
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    success: function(response) {
        $("#AjaxChange").replaceWith(response);
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        alert('Bad connection');
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the error message you are getting? What is the behaviour you are seeing? What is the behaviour you were expecting?

Comment: Typo: `request.is_ajax` -> `request.is_ajax()`.

Comment: What's the value of `request.GET`? What's the output of `print(request.GET)`?

Comment: I gain always default value - 'Main'. I think it's can't find 'site'. request.GET['site'] not work, beacuse ajax returns faild.

Comment: Is your URL query string `?Site=value`, or is it `?site=value`?

Comment: Its ?site=value .  http://127.0.0.1:8000/main?site=Profil it's like that. When it's first page  : http://127.0.0.1:8000/main.

Comment: In that case, please fix the typo in your question. Your question says that the query string is `?Site=value` when in reality, your query string is `?site=value`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Maybe problem is in urls.py. I got: `path('get/ajax/validate/MainSite', htmlMain, name = "html_main"),` and it's possible that he take value from this url?

Comment: Guys I was change in my ajax code `url:/get/ajax/validate/MainSite` to `url:/get/ajax/validate/MainSite + AjaxGetUrlFunction()` and now it's work.But question is: Is good method?

Comment: What's `AjaxGetUrlFunction()`? We won't be able to help you if you don't provide sufficient information.

Comment: Ok sorry, I was edit my post and add this function.

Answer (score 0):

use 'Site' instead of 'site' to get Site=value

```
UrlCut = request.GET.get('Site', 'Main')
```